# How to change a light bulb?

Tags: light-fixture, kitchens

I cannot figure out how to remove the glass globe to change the lightbulbs in my kitchen. I searched and found a similar light fixture to mine that suggests the clips are spring loaded and either pull straight out from the center or towards the ceiling. In this case,  neither is true. There are screws on top of the black clips and it’s too close to the ceiling to get in to unscrew them. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: how about a picture

Comment: A slightly further, less fuzzy photo, please. You got the ceiling in focus.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that _one_ of the retaining arms is sprung.

Comment: Hmm... do you know any  Astronauts? Politicians?  Fishermen? IRS agents?  How about three mimes?

Answer (score 2):

There are fundamentally 3 ways to mount a glass globe.

1- globe screws on (twist lock)

2- Spring clips (inside the globe)

3- older method is to use screws from the side

1- Start with gently turning the globe counter clock wise and observe if it turns.

2- Start with gently pulling the globe downwards

3- Locate the 3 screws on top of the globe near ceiling

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that bracket barely holds it with only 1mm or so of overlap.  I think you're meant to just push the edge of the glass away from the holder by that much so it can drop down.

Are you sure it even *has* a replaceable bulb? All the rage these days is LED fixtures with integral LED emitters.  Those things are semiconductors so they'll last forever.  (the electronic driver is another story).